# Classes HTML em menu com Wordpress

Tags: html, css, wordpress, wordpress-theme

Estou desenvolvendo um tema com `Wordpress` e gostaria que o mesmo possuísse um `menu dropdown`. Criei algumas páginas como `Home`. `Quem Somos`, `Contato` e uma categoria chamada `Produtos` gostaria que a categoria fosse um `dropdown` mostrando todos os posts daquela categoria mas como posso verificar e aplicar as classes referentes ao `dropdown` com `Wordpress`?

Answer (score 1):

Neste caso você precisa antes organizar a hierarquia do menu. Feito isso, geralmente, quando se usa um framework, por exemplo, o CSS já tá formatado, mas como você está fazendo um tema, terá que costurar isso no teu código.

Uma maneira simplificada de fazer isso seria registrar a seguinte função para o seu menu principal dentro do *functions.php* do seu tema.

Coloque algo como:

```
add_theme_support( 'menus' );

function register_theme_menus () {
    register_nav_menus( [
        'primary-menu' => _( 'Menu principal' )
    ] );
}

add_action( 'init', 'register_theme_menus' );
```

Na sua *header.php*, onde está chamando o menu principal atualmente, acrescente o seguinte código para chamar o menu que registramos anteriormente (você também pode acrescentar o mesmo em partes específicas que desejar).

```
<nav id="menu">
    <?php wp_nav_menu(array('theme_location'=>'primary-menu')); ?>
</nav>
```

Exemplo de CSS, porém é importante que você personalize de acordo com o seu interesse:

```
/* Primeiro nível - Hierarquia */
nav#menu ul li {float:left; position:relative; text-transform:uppercase; list-style:none}
nav#menu ul li a {display:block; background:#152635; color:#fff; padding:5px 15px; font-size:14px;}

/* Primeiro nível - Hierarquia */
nav#menu ul li ul {display:none;}
nav#menu ul li ul li a {width:160px;}
nav#menu ul li:hover ul {display:block; position:absolute; top:26px;}

/* Terceiro nível - Hierarquia */
nav#menu ul li ul li ul li {list-style:inside square}
nav#menu ul li ul li ul li a {font-size:11px; color:#ddd}
```

Espero ter ajudado. ;)

Comment: Primeiramente bem vindo! Jovem de preferência não coloque apenas o link, pois ele pode deixar de funcionar etc... Tome um tempo e cite aqui no corpo da resposta a parte do texto que interessa, coloque uma imagem ou algo com mais conteúdo para a comunidade.

Comment: Obrigado pelo Feedback, já alterei minha resposta para algo mais detalhado.